# Simple syrup end result

Tags: syrup

When making a simple syrup, my ratio was four cups water to three cups sugar, what is the end volume?

I ask because i messed up a drink recipe by measuring the next step against the amount of the water and forgetting to take into account the increase in volume due to the sugar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

6 TBS (3 ounces by volume) of granulated sugar, mixed with 4 liquid ounces of water (1/2 cup US), brought to a hard boil in the microwave yielded *just* over 6 liquid ounces of syrup. (A drop of color added for readability)

[image: 1]

I would suspect that it didn't reach 7 ounces because of the air included in the volumetric measurement of granulated sugar.

So 4 cups of water plus 3 cups of granulated sugar would yield just over 6 cups of syrup if not allowed to reduce on the stove.